# Getting model data in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have started using AngularJs and I need some help with controller model data sharing.

I have this html template:

```
<input ng-model="form.search">
```

I know that you can pass it with a function like `FormCtrl.data(form.search)`. However *I would like to know if there are other ways getting model data in controller.*

Comment: Any thing you can to the scope is available to both view and controller. Scope is the glue that makes it happen. Read more about scope

Comment: Well I tried accessing the value from $scope.search in controller. But it is undefined.

Comment: what about `$scope.form.search`?

Comment: console.log($scope.form) = undefined

Comment: Looks like was not able to access the $scope from controller, because I was using the ng-boostrap modal. And I was assuming that `ModalInstanceCtrl` has the access to $scope whatever is on the modal form. But it looks like I need to apply other controller on the form to access the the $scope. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any model data in your Controller, e.g. `console.log($scope.form.search)` will have it printed. You may also want to `ng-init` the the form at the beginning of your controller code: `$scope.form = {}`, before `console.log($scope.form.search)` is invoked.